# Поменять значение

Tags: java

Есть строка с парами ключ=значение; Как можно изменить значение определенного ключа? Например как мне поменять значение ключа KeyB на ValueBB?

```
KeyA=ValueA; KeyB=ValueB; KeyC=ValueC;
```

Comment: Зависит от контекста. Можно регуляркой, можно все считать в мапу, поменять значение, и записать обратно. Если это не одноразовая операцмя, то обычно выбирают второй способ.

Comment: Я попробовал регуляркой ([^=]+)=([^\;]+);\s? и он выдаёт мне 3 группы. 1: KeyA=ValueA;
2: KeyA
3: ValueA
и т.д.

Comment: Самый тупой способ `String test = "KeyA=ValueA; KeyB=ValueB; KeyC=ValueC;";
  String searchedKey= "KeyB";
  String newValue= "MAVAUE";
  int index1 = test.indexOf(searchedKey);
  int index2 = test.indexOf(";", index1+searchedKey.length());
  String newTest = test.substring(0, index1) + searchedKey + "=" + newValue + test.substring(index2);
  System.out.print(newTest);` :)))))

Comment: @AndXor если вам надо определенного ключа, так наверно и регулярку надо делать с учетом имени определенного ключа?

Comment: Само собой, просто мне нужно вернуть эту строку но с новым значением тоесть KeyA=ValueA; KeyB=ValueBB; KeyC=ValueC;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String key = "KeyB";
String value = "new_value";
System.out.println("KeyA=ValueA; KeyB=ValueB; KeyC=ValueC;".replaceAll(String.format("%s=.+?;", key),
                String.format("%s=%s;", key, value)));
// KeyA=ValueA; KeyB=new_value; KeyC=ValueC;
```